# show data by session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

how to display data by session in codeigniter,
i have sample in php like this:

```html
<?php

include "../admin/fungsi/koneksi.php";
$profil=$con->prepare("select * from pasien where username=?");
$profil->execute(array($_SESSION["username"]));
$db=$profil->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);

echo "
<img src='../gambar/12.jpg' alt='HTML5 Icon' style='width:1129px;height:164px;'>
<left style='font-size:28px;color:blue'><i>Profil</i></left><hr color='blue' />
<table style='color:blue;'>

<tr><td>Nama</td><td>:</td><td>".$db["nama"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td>".$db["username"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Jenis Kelamin</td><td>:</td><td>".$db["jk"]."</td></tr>
<tr><td>Alamat</td><td>:</td><td>".$db["alamat"]."</td></tr>
</table>";
?>
```

Comment: u need session_start(); in every page that use $_Session

Comment: add session library in controller or autoload file and access session objects. more details you can find [here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

Comment: Use codeigniter session http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Codeigniter DB http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/index.html

Comment: can you give example code in controller,model and view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first autoload session libaray at config/autoload.php ,

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation');
```

1. store session data

   $admin_id=2;
   $data = array('admin_id' => $admin_id);
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
2. fetch session data

   $admin_id=$this->session->userdata('admin_id');

Comment: thanks for your suggest,but if $admin_id=from database by login where $this->session->set_userdata($data); can all show data in table database.i'm so confused